# With open source software like OpenCart, how much can I alter the core code?

Tags: open-source, opencart

I'm new to working with open source projects and I'm currently looking into OpenCart specifically. Sorry if this question is a bit dumb but how much can I change the code to customize my needs?

Lets say I want to make the `telephone` field not required. Can I simply remove the if statement in the controller?

Or if I would like to add a new field `house_nr` to the checkout; can I just create the database field and alter the code to make it work?

The reason I ask: Wont that break the code again when I update to a new version? What is best practice here? Should I keep a document of every file I altered so I can do it again in a big update?

Comment: There's a technical question, a legal question and a competency question here. Yes/Yes/No, I think.

Comment: I would say maybe/uhm yes/hell yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the core will 100% break when upgrading, but you are free to do so. As always backup often, cos a reinstall will destroy anything else you did.

Use vqmod and custom templates instead. TRicky to work out at first, but you will be very thankfull down the line. Google them to resarch both.

Comment: I'll look into vqmod, thanks! So if I understand it correctly; breaking the core is not the "wrong way" of doing it but not breaking the core is better?

Comment: That is Correct. I promise you will be sorry down the line though if you do. Trying to repeat all the changes you made in a year or three will be a nightmare. Fixing mods you make is much less work, even if there is a major version upgrade like with opencart version 2.